# Javascript 2d arrays remove the same elemets like dropping style

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Forexample, I have an array like this:

```js
const arr = [
 [1, 2, 8],
 [8, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]
];
```

And I want to remove the number 8 from bottom to top like dropping. Forexample:

```js
const arr = [
 [null, null, null],
 [1, 2, 6],
 [7, 5, 9]
];
```

I will replace the nulls later.

Comment: So what approach did you come up with? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your array from the bottom to the top, then inside loop over each row. If the current item you find is an 8 - then drop all previous items in the same row down by one position, and set null on that position for the first row.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 8],
  [8, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  for (let j = 0, l = arr.length; j < l; ++j) {
    if (arr[i][j] == 8) {
      for (let k = i; k > 0; --k) {
        arr[k][j] = arr[k - 1][j];
      }
      arr[0][j] = null;
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```